# How to implement JAAS rdbms with JBose Fuse Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jaas, jbossfuse

I have currently started working at jboss fuse and Jaas. i have previously worked at Json rest and soap api and have command on it. i wanted to  implement JAAS with soap api on jboss fuse.  i have effectively made an application of soap apis however i need to execute jaas on it.

let me explain you my scenario. Lets assume, taking username & password from header in request of soap api. i need to authenticate the user, whether the user have rights to access the operation name (method name), the username & password must be matched from database & also the operation name too. like i have 3 tables in my database first table api_users(contains username, password), second table api_rights (contains operation_name), third table api_user_rights (contains foreign keys user_id and right_id) . My aim is to implement this scenario in JBose fuse using JAAS.
Is there any other approach to achieve this thing.

Help Required.

Step by step tutorial will be great if possible

Comment: Fuse team has a quick start example [here](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts/tree/master/cxf/secure-soap)

Comment: @user7790438 yes i have gone through this example. Need to implement database to authenticate user and it roles.

Comment: Try this [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Security_Guide/files/SecureBroker-JAAS.html)